# How to print/log val in sbt build?

Tags: sbt

If we want to print/log a simple variable like,

```
lazy val config = ConfigFactory.load()
```

And inspect its value in sbt, then how do we do that?

When I just type it in sbt shell, I get:

```
> config

[error] Not a valid command: config

[error] Not a valid project ID: config

[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)

[error] Not a valid key: config (similar: configuration, deploy-configs, conflictManager)

[error] config
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to print something when you type a string in sbt console,you can add

```
lazy val configTest = settingKey[String]("example")

configTest := "config test"
```

Then you will get

```
> configTest
[info] config test
```

Comment: You can also print values from withing the sbt definition code itself, using `println`. By itself, this won't pretty print sbt-specific objects such as a `settingKey` object in any way (they must require their own methods to get their actual values) but you can use this to print regular Scala types from within your build definition code.

Answer (score 4):

To print a variable defined in `build.sbt` in the sbt shell, use `sbt show`.

#### From sbt shell

```
> show {{ variable name }}
```

#### From bash or zsh

```
sbt 'show {{ variable name }}'
```

#### Example

```
sbt 'show scalaVersion'

[info] Loading project definition from [...]/project
[info] Set current project to [...] (in build file:[...])
[info] 2.12.4
```

#### Source

[sbt Reference Manual](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Inspect-the-Build.html#Show+the+value+of+a+setting)